# How to change the url for SEO purposes of a custom module?

Tags: url, url-rewrite

I have the following url for a specific entity

```
brands/index/view/id/1/
```

I would like to rewrite this url to:

```
brands/{{ brand_title }}
```

How is it possible?

Comment: You can use magento url rewrite to add custom rewrite programatically.

Comment: May be use full for  : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/29/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need custom rewrites, you need a custom router. Have a look at this article:

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Basically you need to check if the router is matching your controller action, and if it does, then apply the logic (brand name => brand id) and call the relevant action with the correct parameters.

Comment: Ok, but that is overwriting the default router with a custom one. So very risky as an error would cause site wide havock...

Comment: If at the top of the router, you check if this is a request for your controller, then you can just escape every other route.